# PHP session variables not available on redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect

I'm new to a lot of this so i apologize if this question is obvious. I've looked for an answer for a long time.

I am struggling with the use of a $_SESSION variable on a redirect. I am setting the variable in one page and trying to read it in another, to which the user is redirected from the first page. For some reason, the second page can't read the variable. here's my code so far:

PHP page 1:

```
<?php 
  if(!session_id()) session_start();
  $_SESSION['someVar'] = "someValue";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='/index.php';</script>";
```

PHP page 2 (index.php):

```
<?php
  if(!session_id()) session_start();
  if (empty($_SESSION["someVar"])) {
    echo "no value!";
  } else {
    echo $_SESSION["someVar"];
  }
?>
```

I always get "no value!". I've tried several things to solve this:

1. I separated out the redirect onto a button on page1. doesn't help.
2. I echo the value on page 2 - it comes up as an empty string.
3. I've echo'ed out the session_id() on both pages, and they match.

the really annoying thing about all this is that the code works perfectly when i run it locally (using a virtual host). it's only when i load it onto a 'real' server that i fails, which suggests to me that the problem is somewhere else, but i don't know where to look.

Comment: Check the PHP error log for "Headers already sent" warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your session directory is not writable.

using [session_save_path()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php), here is a small function to test that.

```
function check_session_path() {
    echo is_writable(session_save_path()) ? "writable." : "not writable.";
}
```

in your php page 1:

```
<?php
check_session_path();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. The output showed it was not writeable. I contacted my website host company and they changed it. It works now.